# How can I paint random values under a curve Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, colors

I want to paint the random numbers that are shown under the curve of a color, and those that are above another color, I tried putting my values in arrays and putting an if, I have been trying but I have not obtained result, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x):
    return (np.exp(-x))*x**2
f = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = func(f)
yw=np.array(y)
plt.plot(f, y)
plt.axhline(y=0.6, xmin=0, xmax=10)
h=np.random.randn(1000)
h2=np.array(h)
#if(h2>yw):
 #   plt.plot(f,h,'mo')
#else:        
plt.plot(f, y)
plt.plot(f,h,'co')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,0.6012)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping over each value, check if its corresponding value is greater or less that the function, and plotting each point with a different color.

I tried this:

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    if h[i] > func(f[i]):
        plt.plot(f[i],h[i],'co')
    else:
        plt.plot(f[i],h[i],'ro')
```

This is the image I get:

[image: output plot]